# Открытие PDF файла в Android

Tags: pdf, android, java

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно открыть PDF файл внутри приложения, а не использовать сторонние программы. В интернете много примеров, но они все одинаковые и открывают pdf в сторонних программах, а мне нужно, чтобы pdf открылось внутри моего приложения. 
Может кто знает или делал?

Comment: Можно попробовать воспользоваться чужим трудом. Посмотрите например этот проект:  
http://sourceforge.net/p/andpdf/code/108/tree/tag/Beta_0_1_16/AndroidPdfViewer/

Comment: что в итоге, сделали? расскажите как

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: iText вообще-то для создания pdf